# Gravity Forms Update post meta from template

Tags: custom-field, post-meta, plugin-gravity-forms

I created a form called 'Books' which has the fields:

- Title (Post Title)
- Author
- Genre (Dropdown - fantasy, horror, drama... etc)
- ISBN Number
- Status (Dropdown - Default Option - Published, additional option - Promoted)

This form creates and populates a custom post type called books, which has the custom meta fields:

- Author
- Genre
- ISBN Number
- Status
- Promoter

I have a second form called 'Promoter' which show up in my single-books.php template file in my wordpress theme.  The form shows up on the bottom of the page if the status is "Published" with the single text field for a person to enter their name for support and change the status from published to promoted.  I spent a lot of time on the gravity forums site looking for an answer, and I came up with:

```
add_action("gform_post_submission_5", "books_promoter", 10, 4);
function books_promoter($entry, $form) {
        global $post;
        global $wp_query;

        $post_id = get_the_ID(); // $entry['post_id'];

        $post_data['status'] = get_post_meta($postID,'status', true);
        $post_data['promoter'] = get_post_meta($postID,'promoter', true);

        $status = $entry['5'];
        $promoter = $entry['6'];

        update_post_meta($post_id, 'books_status', $status );
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'books_promoter', $promoter );
}
```

This function gets the post ID and blank post meta field and then updates the post meta.  For some reason though it does not work.  I think it might be with the $post_id inside the template file loop, but I was wondering if anyone had any opinions on a better way to do this.

Comment: You are calling it `$post_id` and then later `$postID` - perhaps this is the cause for the problem?

Comment: @GhostToast you're my hero, I can't believe I just did that, amateur hour.  Thanks again, worked perfectly.  Also had to change gform_post_submission to gform_after_submission since post is depricated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the repair, for good measure and anyone curious:

```
add_action("gform_after_submission_5", "books_promoter", 10, 4);
function books_promoter($entry, $form) {
        global $post;
        global $wp_query;

        $post_id = get_the_ID(); // $entry['post_id'];

        $post_data['status'] = get_post_meta($post_id,'status', true);
        $post_data['promoter'] = get_post_meta($post_id,'promoter', true);

        $status = $entry['5'];
        $promoter = $entry['6'];

        update_post_meta($post_id, 'books_status', $status );
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'books_promoter', $promoter );
}
```

Comment: You may want to look at `gform_update_meta()` instead of `update_post_meta()`. As far as I'm aware gravity forms stores entries in a separate table. So while `update_post_meta()` may work for lower form ID numbers it will start to fail once your form entries exceed the number of blog posts on your site (if that makes sense)